# How to lock users with PAM in Scientific Linux 5.5?

Tags: pam

I need to lock the users that are trying to log in via SSHD after 5 unsuccessful login tries. I already googled for it, but I just can see it working:

```
root@server:~# faillog -u testuser
Login       Failures Maximum Latest                   On
testuser        0        0
```

The Maximum faillog is always 0 for a reason...

**QUESTION**: What packages do I need to have installed? What settings do I have to make? I know that I must have "UsePAM yes" in the sshd_config, that's OK. Does it counts that where am I putting the PAM lines in ex.: system-auth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use the pam_tally2 module of pam(already built-in on pam package)
- Add the following line on the `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` file

  ```
   auth required pam_tally.so onerr=fail deny=5 unlock_time=21600
  ```

Where:

- `deny=5`: Number of tries
- `onerr=fail`: Default behavior if something weird happens to pam
- `unlock_time`: Number of seconds to unlock again the account.

Now, is just use pam(UsePam=yes) on sshd.